# Rigorous proof to show that the $15$-Puzzle problem is unsolvable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, invariance

So this is supposedly a very popular puzzle by Sam Loyd. (I don't want answerers to provide solutions directly from some website etc. I mean, an ingenious solution is more welcome please.)

> [image]
>
> Now, as you see all numbers are arranged in ascending order except the last two. The rule of the game is to move a numbered block which is adjacent to the blank space and create another blank place in its original position (I mean, you just shift the position of blank space around by sliding the numbers around) .
>
> Now the question goes as, can you arrange all the numbers in the correct ascending order? (The final outcome would be just interchange the positions of $15$ and $14$).

I know of a solution using a very clever trick of invariance (the invariant seemed quite non-trivial to me ;-P). Can others here come up with some interesting solutions?

Comment: So this is just a 15-puzzle?

Comment: @ericw31415 I don't know if it's *just a*... but it seemed quite interesting and the mathematics behind it didn't seem *just* trivial to me ...

Comment: this puzzle is impossible to solve

Comment: It is quite easy to see that it's impossible, but I can't explain mathematically.

Comment: @Vasya  I want concrete mathematical proof

Comment: I know of a kind a proof that kind of blew me up and my thoughts... I found it thoroughly interesting... @ericw31415

Comment: Every move swaps the blank space with an adjacent block. In the end the blank space must return to its original position, but this requires an even number of moves. Now consider the parity of the desired permutation.

Comment: It's not just "a" 15-puzzle.  It is "the" 15-puzzle.  Very well known.  Should read up on it.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle Upshot.  All even permutations are solveable and all odd permutations are not.  This is an odd permutation.

Comment: @Rahul Ok... I have proved its impossible in odd number of steps. Now?

Comment: By the way, I don't think its as easy or as trivial to pin down as must of us like to imply it is.  When Sam Lloyd came up with it, determining which solutions were solvable  and which werent was considered extremely challenging.

Comment: @fleablood Ok, so I have proved its impossible in odd number of steps. Now, what's a convincing argument to eliminate the even case... Can you come up with something?

Comment: This is an excellent example of an everyday situation that can not be handled by a computer (the computer could find the solution if there is one), but only by "real" mathematics. Someone had to come up with the proper "invariant" for the impossibility proof. Note that it took two thousand years to prove that you cannot trisect an angle or double a cube.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I came to know of an invariant, very clever one (not the complete only a hint)... should I tell it to you or wait for some time till I receive some answers etc.?

Comment: What even case?  Transposing the 14 and 15 is an odd permutation.

Comment: @fleablood I meant that I want to show it is impossible to slove it in even number of moves

Comment: @Soham Can you give us your "clever invariant" now, or do you want to wait for some more time to receive answers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be shown using some elementary abstract algebra.

In short, a puzzle configuration is not solvable if and only if it's an odd number of swaps away from the solved state, like the one in your image is (14 and 15 swapped = 1 swap).  I used this fact a few years ago to quickly generate random configurations for a 15-puzzle app I used to have in the App Store.

Reference:  https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/15puzzle.pdf